# Gradient multi color each face?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

Basically I want to make gradient color like this in cycles, is that possible ?

[image: 1]]

Here the link for the lowpoly apple model I made:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzM1zdTMJ5ombC1BNmN5VmJyemM/view?usp=sharing

Thanks you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use faces normals to obtain the colors of the faces (more or less randomly) and use UV input to give them a little gradient effect (or some lamps also).

For the color :

- Use "texture coordinate" and "normal" as input
- Add a vector mapping (this is usefull after to tune the faces orientation by rotating x, y or z and change the colors)
- Separate the coordinates
- Add a color ramp to each so that you can modulate each intensity
- Combine them and use it as a color input for the shader

For the little gradient effect :

- Use "UV" input of the texture coordinate input
- Separate and use X or Y (U or V)
- Add a color ramp to tune the value

Use both by mixing them and link to the shader.

[image]

This is not the exact same colors as your picture, but the same kind of effect. You'll probably have to tune : color ramps, orientations, eventually inverting X, Y, Z...
[image]