# Palette Texturing

Tags: materials

I was wondering what node combination I would need to achieve the coloring shown in the attached picture. I've been fiddling with a color ramp for a while but couldn't get the result I wanted. I've focused most of my learning in modeling so I don't know much about materials, so any tips are valuable to me.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient multi color each face?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55906/gradient-multi-color-each-face)

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show screenshots of your work? Where exactly are you stuck?